# Gatling not logging to influxdb?

Tags: gatling, influxdb

I've tried following the guide at http://gatling.io/docs/2.2.3/realtime_monitoring/index.html to log my test results to influxdb and display the data in a grafana that I have previously set up. However I can't see any of the data that gatling is supposed to log anywhere in influxdb.

I've edited by influxdb.conf file so that it contains the following fields:

```
[[graphite]]
enabled = true
database = "gatlingdb"
bind-address = ":2003"
protocol = "tcp"
consistency-level = "one"
name-separator = "."


templates = [
  "gatling.*.*.*.count measurement.simulation.request.status.field",
  "gatling.*.*.*.min measurement.simulation.request.status.field",
  "gatling.*.*.*.max measurement.simulation.request.status.field",
  "gatling.*.*.*.percentiles50 measurement.simulation.request.status.field",
  "gatling.*.*.*.percentiles75 measurement.simulation.request.status.field",
  "gatling.*.*.*.percentiles95 measurement.simulation.request.status.field",
  "gatling.*.*.*.percentiles99 measurement.simulation.request.status.field"
]
```

and my gatling.conf file contains the following fields:

```
 data {
writers = [console, file, graphite]      # The list of DataWriters to which Gatling write simulation data (currently supported : console, file, graphite, jdbc)
console {
  #light = false                # When set to true, displays a light version without detailed request stats
}

graphite {
  #light = false              # only send the all* stats
  host = "127.0.0.1"         # The host where the Carbon server is located
  port = 2003                # The port to which the Carbon server listens to (2003 is default for plaintext, 2004 is default for pickle)
  protocol = "tcp"           # The protocol used to send data to Carbon (currently supported : "tcp", "udp")
  rootPathPrefix = "gatling" # The common prefix of all metrics sent to Graphite
  #bufferSize = 8192          # GraphiteDataWriter's internal data buffer size, in bytes
  #writeInterval = 1          # GraphiteDataWriter's write interval, in seconds
}
```

Whenever i run my gatling tests I see no error messages or anything that indicates that anything is wrong, but I cannot see anything in the influxd logs that indicates that anything has been logged to influxdb, nor can I see any data in the gatlingdb database. I am using influxdb v0.10 and gatling v2.2.3 on Ubuntu

Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated to influxdb v1.1 and the problem seemed to have resolved itself from doing that

Comment: I am using influx db 1.7.9 and having the same problem. What I can do?

Comment: Same issue with InfluxDB 1.7.9 and Gatling bundle 3.3.1